# convert datetime to another format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the following date time string `'2021-03-25T20:00:00.0+02:00'` to format `'2021-03-25T20:00:00.0+0200'` .
What is the proper way to convert it ? is it a specific ISO ?
Until now i parse the str into date time by:

```
   from dateutil.parser import parse
   date=parse('2021-03-25T20:00:00.0+02:00')
```

How can i print my desirable format ?

Answer (score 1):

Both representations are valid ISO 8601 since [the time zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) may be `Z`, `±hh:mm`, `±hhmm` or `±hh`. However, `.isoformat()` only gets you one with the colon.

Once you have a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import zoneinfo
>>> local_now = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Helsinki'))
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 26, 11, 9, 29, 164846, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Helsinki'))
```

you can call `.isoformat()` on it with a suitable resolution specifier and slice off the third-last character:

```
>>> formatted = local_now.isoformat('T', 'seconds')
'2021-03-26T11:09:29+02:00'
>>> a, colon, b = formatted.rpartition(':')
>>> a + b
'2021-03-26T11:09:29+0200'
```

You may want to add extra validation to ensure there really is a timezone specifier in the string (maybe assert that the fifth-last character is a `+`/`-`) before slicing.

## Edit

Another option, now that I think of it, is native `strftime()`:

```
>>> local_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2021-03-26T11:09:29+0200'
```